# Base64 Encoding Images in CSS

Tags: .net, css, vb.net, base64

I am writing a little project to parse a CSS file, and base64 encode all the background images.

While I am able to parse the CSS correctly, it seems that everytime I try to convert the image file into a base64Encoded string, the string returned is always exactly the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the encoder.  Please assume that all image paths are passing correctly to the method.  In this instance, all images are fully qualified urls, so the first section of the method is what is doing the conversion.

```
Public Sub EncodeImage(ByVal _File As String)
    If _File.StartsWith("http") OrElse _File.StartsWith("https") Then
        Using _wc As New WebClient()
            Common.SetAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing20()
            _wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13")
            _wc.DownloadFile(_File, "c:\temp.png")
            Dim _d As Byte() = _wc.DownloadData(_File)
            ImageStrings.Add(New ImageTyping() With {
                             .SourceFile = _File,
                             .Base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(_d)
                         })
            _d = Nothing
        End Using
    Else
        Using _fs As New FileStream(_File, IO.FileMode.Open)
            Using _br As New BinaryReader(_fs)
                Dim _i As Byte() = _br.ReadBytes(_fs.Length)
                ImageStrings.Add(New ImageTyping() With {
                             .SourceFile = _File,
                             .Base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(_i)
                             })
                _i = Nothing
                _br.Close()
            End Using
            _fs.Close()
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Each and every string returned from this is: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAAGXcA1uAAAAKUlEQVRIx2P4//+/DwwzUJUzoiRGNYxqGNUwGDSMWjBqwagFoxbQAAMAfS9kqktT8qQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

Comment: Some things to note: Given it's a CSS and can have redundancy, I'd create a "cache list" of converted images and save a round-trip if possible. Also, you probably want to be using either `.StartsWith("https")` or, better yet, use the `Uri` object and check if it's a valid URL before handing it off to a `WebClient`

Comment: Now, creating a "cached list".  Still the same issue.  I am doing a List(of ImageEncodingTyping), whose properties are OriginalFilePath as String, EncodedString As String, and it is still happenning.  The list is getting populated, but, every instance of EncodedString is the value I posted above, even though OriginalFilePath lists the correct (all different) images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the User-Agent header string, and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

The base64 string you posted is a valid 24x24 pixel fully-transparent PNG file. Your base64 code seems to work, but the files you convert are probably not those you want to convert.

Comment: Every single file that is getting passed to this, is valid, and are the right files.

Comment: I have also verified each file, by _wc.DownLoadFile(_File, "mypath"), putting a breakpoint and checking the file that gets written.  Each written image, is exactly what they are supposed to be.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know the answer.